# Developing Outlook plugin with Visual C# 2008 Express?

Tags: c#, outlook, visual-studio-express

I'm looking to experiment with developing an Outlook plugin. I'm using the express edition of Visual Studio, and it seems the Outlook integration feature is missing from the Express edition (intentionally).

Is that indeed the case?

Are there 3rd party libraries that allow connecting to the Outlook model with the Express edition?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to install the [Office Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb652780.aspx) and reference those.. then you should be good to go.

Comment: The explanation I was missing was eventually in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb646840.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Add-in-Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/). They say that Visual C# .NET 2008 Express is supported. It is however not that cheap (US$ 349).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Hacking Outlook](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/38-windows/222-hacking-outlook-com-interop.html) The big problem is that OUtlook Express is something that Microsoft really don't want you to extend and the COM interface is far from complete, far from documented and infact definitely not the recommended way to do things. However there isn't a recommended way so the only choice left is to use what you can i.e. the COM interface. 
So automate the interace you are basically back to old techniques such as using Windows messages and hooking the interface - good luck it isn't easy.
PS -- Full Outlook is another matter and is just a matter of creating a standard Office add in.

Comment: You are referring to Outlook Express, but I'm talking about Microsoft Outlook. Do they have the same COM interfaces?